# Face texture lighter than other faces but they're using the same material

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm fairly new to blender and I've been having a problem with an object's face. It's significantly lighter than the others but they all use the same material and nodes. Any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks!

[image: The face]

The lighter face

---

[image: Wall selection]

It's assigned to the Wall material along with the other wall faces

---

[image: nodes]

[image: other face with no problem]

Uses the same config with other wall faces

---

Comment: my guess is that those lighter faces have reversed normals, can you check your normals orientation?

Comment: Woah, it worked! Thank you so much! I think the problem was from the way I created the face. I extruded the rightmost vertex upwards and then filled up the hole. Thanks again!

Comment: yes inverted faces can be easily created by filling or extrusion, if something doesn't fit like this, react differently or is it based on your faces then it is mostly inverted face, I am glad that it works now